# AutoHotkey script - send key stroke after X minutes of inactivity (not working?)

Tags: autohotkey

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
SetTimer, CheckIdle, 5000

CheckIdle:
    If ( A_TimeIdle > 15000 ) {
        ControlSend,, {space}, WindowTitle
    }
Return
```

This is my code and I'm sure I got everything correct, but it seems to send the keystrokes every 5 seconds, which is the interval set in the timer.
It's behaving like the if statement is always true and it doesn't reset A_TimeIdle.
Can someone help?

Comment: Apparently, ControlSend doesn't reset the idle time so you'll have to store the time of the last issued ControlSend in an additional variable and check it as well.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work with Send. ControlSend doesn't work in a background app anyway, only if there is a text box open

Comment: Also be aware that `CheckIdle:` runs one at the very start of the script, because you have no `return` after the `SetTimer` command.  
Labels do **not** stop the flow of execution.

Comment: @wOxxOm You could also `mousemove,1,1,100, R` (move mouse 1 pixel) to reset idle time.